# Child bloc calling its ancestor mapEventToState

Tags: flutter-bloc

I'm trying to create a `CustomBloc` that handles common events. `CustomBloc` is extended by many other Blocs to add functionality.
My problem is the call of `super.mapEventToState` in `CustomBloc` descendants never gets executed.

```dart
class CustomBloc extends Bloc<BlocEvent, BlocState> {
  CustomBloc(BlocState initialState) : super(initialState) 
  @override
  Stream<BlocState> mapEventToState(BlocEvent event) async* {
    if (event is BlocInitialEvent) {
      yield BlocInitialState(BlocStatus.blocBusy)
      try {
         //do something
        yield BlocInitialState(BlocStatus.blocReady);
      } catch (e) {
        yield BlocInitialState(BlocStatus.blocError);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now let's subclass our custom bloc:

```dart
class HomeBloc extends CustomBloc {
  HomeBloc(BlocState initialState) : super(initialState);
 
  @override
  Stream<BlocState> mapEventToState(BlocEvent event) async* {
    super.mapEventToState(event);// the event is never dispatched to CustomBloc
  //Handle more events
  }
}

HomeBloc(BlocInitialState(BlocStatus.blocReady)).Add(BlocInitialEvent);// BlocInitialEvent never gets dispatched to the ancestor class
```

Note that if I don't override `mapEventToState` in `HomeBloc` everything works fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to yield states from `super.mapEventToState(event);`

So try calling `yield* super.mapEventToState(event);`